# Unable to install gdc-client in the conda environment

Tags: conda

I want to download a set of image files from the GDC portal within the conda environment.

I want to do something like this:

```
conda install -c bioconda gdc-client
gdc-client download -m  /home/melissachua/CODEX/gdc_manifest_20211027_035232
```

Error message:

```
> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
> solve. Solving environment: failed with repodata from
> current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment:
> failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Solving environment: | Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible
> packages. This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
> failed
> 
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
> incompatible with each other:
> 
> Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following
> specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
> 
>   - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
>   - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
> 
> Your installed version is: 2.31
```

Answer (score 0):

An error like this is caused by conflicts with already existing packages in your environemtn. A simple fix could be to create an environment for installing gdc to it. You will also need the `conda-forge` channel for this:

```
conda create -n gdc -c bioconda -c conda-forge gdc-client
conda activate gdc
gdc-client download -m  /home/melissachua/CODEX/gdc_manifest_20211027_035232
```

Comment: `Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError:`

Comment: You need to add `-c conda-forge`, see my updated answer. I tested it on my linux64 machine and it works

Answer (score 0):

change your python version to 2.7X